# Cron job failed after some time

Tags: google-app-engine

i have created a cron job which is run every 5 minutes.  but when i deployed to the server it running successfully  half an hour (approx). it stop to running after that. 
  Message show on the server is="on time failed"   i have se Google App Engine.

Comment: What's the relevance of the google-app-engine tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your webhost provide cronjobs to use so often? some hosts don't like that if used to much or if the crons are to heavy..

Comment: i ment that the cronjob is to much for the server to resolve ( some webhosts only allow a specific amount of cronjobs )